# css is not working in magento 2 cart page

Tags: magento, magento2

I have issue in cart page of my website . Currently home page and product pages are loading correctly but the cart page have issue  Css and js fies in the cart page is not working

Please help to solve this . I have seen this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49363/magento-2-stylesheet-not-loading

But  I am not sure i can apply that solution . Please check .

I have tried  `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` ,but still the cart page  is same

[image]

Comment: Can you share the logs from var/log ?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Tried those console commands in that order?

Comment: if i did sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade then magento version will upgrade ? then there will be so many errors

Comment: Well try only to compile maybe, that may help with your installation :) Then leave upgrade out

Comment: but setup:upgrade does not upgrade magento version, it jsut makes packages and databse up to date. Something like that. It should not give issues, unless you have a lot ofcustom adjusments

Answer (score 2):

You are facing problem of css and js page load design after installation in magento2

please follow the following step-:

open the terminal and navigate to magento web root

```
cd /var/www/html/magento2
```

Step 1.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Step 2.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Step 3.

make sure apache “rewrite_module” is enable and then restart the server

Step 4.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2
```

Step 5.

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2
```

Step 6.

delete cache folder under var/cache

et me know if any issue. :)

Comment: Have you chance to look into this?